# Stripping html tags from source code

Tags: java, android, html, regex

```
HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String ResponseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
table = ResponseBody.substring(ResponseBody.indexOf("<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\">"));
table = table.substring(0, table.indexOf("</table>"));  

String htmlString = table;
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\r", "<br/>");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\n", " ");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\'", "&#39;");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");

TextView WORK = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HTML);
WORK.setText(htmlString);
```

I am using regular expressions to extract the `HTML` code. This is my code. It seems correct but the table(substring) is what is being returned not the extracted text. Does anybody know why???

Comment: It is impossible to use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Instead use an HTML parsing library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)  You've got to read the answer here.  It's fantastic (and the most upvoted answer on SO)

Comment: thanks guys I ended up having to change the whole process to put it into a 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the new String object as source for your TextView. Change this:

```
WORK.setText(htmlString);
```

to the following:

```
WORK.setText(noHTMLString);
```